# C# Create gradient depending on color image

Tags: c#, image-processing, linear-gradients

I'm searching a C# way to create a color gradient depending on a image source.
I found nothing on Internet but the goal is to reproduce what Instagram do with stories.
For exemple from this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m54ze.jpg
To this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRKCp.jpg

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Resize picture wxh to column 1xh.
2. Resize column 1xh to background size.
3. (Gaussian blur)

Comment: The result is not what I expected
From this : https://imgur.com/a/ffVHlhD
To this : https://imgur.com/a/79Et3II

Comment: Finally after talking with my designer, the result is not perfect but it suit us ;)